# How can I get a list of tables in a database without a timestamp column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

How can I get a list of tables in a database without a timestamp column?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [INFORMATION SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204(SQL.80).aspx) views:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T where NOT EXISTS 
  (
      select 1 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       where TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
         and TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
         and TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
         and DATA_TYPE = 'timestamp' -- or the literal representing timestamp data type
  )
```

Comment: Since I'm asking for tables only, I added:
and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using SYS.TABLES/SYS.COLUMNS:

```
SELECT name FROM SYS.TABLES 
 WHERE object_id NOT IN (select object_id 
                           FROM SYS.COLUMNS
                          WHERE system_type_id = 189)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx)

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    sys.objects
WHERE
    OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'TableHasTimestamp') = 0 --null if not a table
```